# System freezes after logging in after one failed attempt

Tags: login, 18.04

If I enter my password correct first time, I login as normal.

If I enter my password wrong, it says invalid password. If I attempt to enter the correct password now then the screen freezes and doesn't go to dock as normal. I must restart using a physical button or shutdown to get out. Login works normally after restart, assuming I get it right first time.

EDIT:

After entering a wrong password, if I click cancel and then go back to my user to login, it works fine.

Comment: Just my research.
After the screen freezes, I can use hardware power button to suspend the PC (no shutdown) and then wake it up, then the logon screen works properly regardless if I use wrong or correct password - the screen doesn't freeze this time.

Comment: Check the gear next to `Sign In` button after the first bad password and make sure it hasn't changed your Desktop option to a broken one not setup for you yet.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't know to what gear button you are referring to. On the login screen there is option to switch user, cancel unlocking and to unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a known bug.

The "Purple Screen of Death" occurs when GNOME fails to launch and this commonly occurs due to the reason in the OP.

A fix would be to switch to a different desktop environment as the problem only occurs with GNOME.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1766137

Comment: You should add the bug to your answer.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1766137